# Define an operator with the distributive property

Tags: symbolic, operators

I would like to define the `⊕` operator with distributive, associative, and commutative properties - so that Mathematica can symbolically simplify expressions I use it in. For example:

```
in := Simplify[a b ⊕ a c]
out := a (b ⊕ c)
```

I've already given the `⊕` operator the Flat and Orderless attributes, giving the operator the other two properties I would like, but I can't figure distribution out.

Specifically, what I'm trying to do is define an operator which has the symbolic properties of Plus, but which does not evaluate against numbers, e.g

```
in := 2⊕2
out := 2⊕2
```

is a fully simplified expression.

Comment: What should be the output of `Simplify[2 a b\[CirclePlus]a c\[CirclePlus]a d]` or `Simplify[2 + a b\[CirclePlus]a c\[CirclePlus]a d]`?

Answer (score 10):

This would perhaps do what you want:

```
CirclePlus /: 
 Simplify[CirclePlus[pre___, a_ b_, mid___, a_ c_, post___]] := 
 Simplify@Apply[CirclePlus, 
   Simplify /@ {pre, mid, a Simplify[CirclePlus[b, c]], post}]
```

Since `Distribute` by default only works with `Plus`, I associate the distributive property with `CirclePlus` manually when `Simplify` is applied. I then allow `Simplify` to be applied recursively to the result.

**Edit**

Thanks to Karsten 7 for pointing out that the special case of `CirclePlus` with a single argument should also be handled. The `Flat` attribute by itself doesn't do that because it only kicks in at the pattern recognition stage and not as a simplification rule. So you could add the following:

```
CirclePlus[x : Except[_CirclePlus]] := x

Simplify[a b⊕a c]

(* ==> a (b⊕c) *)
```

I added the `Except` condition in case you already gave `CirclePlus` the `Flat` attribute of `Plus`.

Comment: Wow I didn't think their was a way.

Comment: I get `CirclePlus[a (b\[CirclePlus]c)]` as the output for `Simplify[a b\[CirclePlus]a c]` using your code.

Comment: @Karsten7. Yes, that's what I intended. It's consistent with the operator precedence rules.

Comment: But that is not the expected output shown in the example. Are you assuming `CirclePlus[x_] := x`? Also one should not give `CirclePlus` the attribute `Flat` as the OP did.

Comment: @Karsten7. Indeed, I forgot about that. Now it should be fixed.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the responses. I tested it out and it seems to work for the basic case of `Simplify[a b⊕a c]`, but not on more complicated expressions, like `Simplify[a d b ⊕a d c]`.

Comment: @Elaeum That case is also easy to take care of. I've added it. The recursion just has to re-examine the new `CirclePlus` factor individually to see if it can be factored further.