# Defining the Distributive Depth of an Operator

Tags: linear-algebra, operators

I am working on defining the relations between Bras and Kets in Mathematica, and I am using the CircleDot operator to represent multiplication. I seem to have some trouble defining how operations on expressions containing CircleDot distribute into the expression.

The behavior I am trying to achieve is:

```
ConjugateTranspose[2 I\[CircleDot]Bra[x]]
(* should yield -2 I \[CircleDot]Ket[x] *)
```

I have already defined the ConjugateTranspose of a Bra, so this already works:

```
ConjugateTranspose[Bra[x]]
(* already properly yields Ket[x] *)
```

I have tried this:

```
ConjugateTranspose[Times[u_, (c_ /; NumberQ[c])]\[CircleDot]Bra[x_]] ^:=
```

Conjugate[Times[u, (c /; NumberQ[c])]][CircleDot]Ket[x]

As per [Define an operator with the distributive property](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94736/define-an-operator-with-the-distributive-property), I have tried:

```
CircleDot /: 
 Simplify[CircleDot[pre___, a_ b_, mid___, Ket[x_], post___]] := 
 Simplify@Apply[CircleDot, 
   Simplify /@ {pre, mid, Simplify[a b], Ket[x], post}]
```

What does seem to work is this:

```
ConjugateTranspose[I \[CircleDot]Bra[x]]
(* yields -I Ket[x] *)
```

But it doesn't seem that the ConjugateTranspose will distribute and apply to the `2 I` and `Bra[x]` individually and I'm a bit stuck. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried *not* putting `Simplify[]` in your rule definitions?