# Define a distributive function?

Tags: function-construction, attributes

[Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94736/define-an-operator-with-the-distributive-property) is a related question, but not quite what I'm after.

I would like to define a function `f[x_]` that has the distributive attribute, such that:

```
f[a+b+c]
```

> `f[a]+f[b]+f[c]`

Of course I could do

```
f[Plus[x_,y___]]:=f[x]+f[Plus[y]]
```

but I suspect that this would be much slower than an actual `Attribute`. Unfortunately, I cannot find `Distributive` in the list of allowed [attributes](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Attributes.html).

How should one define such a property to make sure that it performs as efficiently as possible?

Comment: Do you know about `Distribute`? e.g. `Distribute[f[a + b + c]]`

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch wow, thank you! Good to know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f[x__Plus] := Plus @@ (f /@ (List @@ x))
```

This is also about the same speed as:

```
f[x__Plus] := Map[f, x]
```

Which is also about the same speed as:

```
f[x__Plus] := Distribute[Unevaluated[f[x]]]
```

You can test the efficiency of this like so:

```
var = Sum[a[i], {i, 1, 100000}];
AbsoluteTiming[f[var];]
```

I am reasonably sure there isn't an attribute based solution, and I believe that most of the built-in functions that aren't coded in C rely on pattern matching to manage the distributive property. The trick here is to avoid relying on pattern matching more often than necessary: this splits out every summand in a single replacement.