# Distribute dot and multiplication on a sum

Tags: list-manipulation, simplifying-expressions, dot

I have a simple problem, I would like to get the following:

```
In=  Distribute[a.(b+c)*d]
Out= a.b*d+a.c*d
```

Meaning that I would like the dot product and the multiplication to be distributed over the sum. I want it to work for more complicated patterns too, such as `a.(b+c+d+e).f*x.(y+z)`. How can that be done? 
Maybe a function can be defined, to replace mathematica's `Dot`, that somehow is distributive over all inputs? I tried using [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/165884/define-a-distributive-function) but could only make a function distributive over one input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewriting problems can often be directly solved with replacements. Since there are a relatively small number of replacement rules involved, that would be my go to. I use `ReplaceRepeated` (`//.`) in `dist` below to implement these replacements, as there may be several layers of replacements to unravel as the distribution continues:

```
dist[expr_] := 
  expr //. {Dot[x_, y_Plus] :> Map[x.# &, y], 
    Dot[x_Plus, y_] :> Map[#.y &, x], 
    Times[x_, y_Plus] :> Map[x*# &, y], 
    Times[x_Plus, y_] :> Map[#*y &, x]};
```

This preserves the ordering of the arguments, but *Mathematica* always assumes that `Times` is commutative, so it will still rearrange the outputs some as a result:

```
dist[a.(b + c)*d]
```

> d a.b + d a.c

```
dist[a.(b + c + d + e).f*x.(y + z)]
```

> x.y a.b.f + x.z a.b.f + x.y a.c.f + x.z a.c.f + x.y a.d.f + 
>    x.z a.d.f + x.y a.e.f + x.z a.e.f

Answer (score 4):

I believe what you're looking for is `TensorExpand[a.(b+c)*d]`:

```
In[1]:= TensorExpand[a.(b + c)*d]
Out[1]= d a.b + d a.c
```

Comment: Be aware that TensorExpand is notorious for being extremely slow if you have more than a couple terms. This is because TensorExpand uses a lot of rules behind the scenes.