How to impose distributivity over custom tensor product
I have written a custom tensor-like product called "TProduct[a,b]"
ClearAll[TProduct]

TProduct /: TProduct[a_, b_] TProduct[c_, d_] := TProduct[a c, b  d]
TProduct /: TProduct[a_, b_] (f_ + g_) := TProduct[a, b]  f + TProduct[a, b] g
TProduct[c_ ?NumberQ  f_, g_] := c  TProduct[f, g]
TProduct[f_, c_ ?NumberQ  g_] := c  TProduct[f, g]
   
Format[TProduct[a_, b_]] := Row[{"[(", a, ") \[CircleTimes] (", b, ")]"}]

This behaves exactly as I would like, with one exception. When I input:
TProduct[x, y] + 2 (TProduct[x, y] + TProduct[y, x])

It does not simplify to
3TProduct[x, y] + 2 TProduct[y, x].

This is an issue with the fact that Mathematica doesn't seem to know that I want
$$c (x \otimes y + z \otimes w) = c x\otimes y  +c z \otimes w$$.
I thought this wouldn't be a problem, I can simply add the line:
TProduct /: c_?NumberQ (TProduct[a_, b_] + rest_) := c  TProduct[a, b] + c  rest

But this doesn't work? I get the error 'Tag TProduct in c_?NumberQ (rest_+TProduct[a_,b_]) is too deep for an assigned rule to be found.' Why is this failing? I would have thought this line was nearly identical to the (functioning) line:
TProduct /: TProduct[a_, b_] (f_ + g_) := TProduct[a, b]  f + TProduct[a, b] g.


For completeness this is the entirety of my code:
(*Define the tensor product operator*)
ClearAll[TProduct]
TProduct /: TProduct[a_, b_] TProduct[c_, d_] := TProduct[a c, b  d]
TProduct /: TProduct[a_, b_] (f_ + g_) := 
 TProduct[a, b]  f + TProduct[a, b] g
TProduct /: c_?NumberQ (TProduct[a_, b_] + rest_) := 
 c  TProduct[a, b] + c  rest
TProduct[c_ ?NumberQ  f_, g_] := c  TProduct[f, g]
TProduct[f_, c_ ?NumberQ  g_] := c  TProduct[f, g]

(*Format the tensor product to display using \[CircleTimes]*)
Format[TProduct[a_, b_]] := 
 Row[{"[(", a, ") \[CircleTimes] (", b, ")]"}]

(*Define an operation that expands brackets*)
ClearAll[ExpandTProduct]
ExpandTProduct[expr_] := expr //. {
   TProduct[a_ + b_, c_] :> TProduct[a, c] + TProduct[b, c], 
   TProduct[a_, b_ + c_] :> TProduct[a, b] + TProduct[a, c]
   }

(*Define an operation that factors the tensor product*)
ClearAll[FactorTProduct]
FactorTProduct[expr_] := expr //. {
   TProduct[a_, c_] + TProduct[b_, c_] :> TProduct[a + b, c], 
   TProduct[a_, c_] - TProduct[b_, c_] :> TProduct[a - b, c], 
   TProduct[a_, b_] + TProduct[a_, c_] :> TProduct[a, b + c], 
   TProduct[a_, b_] - TProduct[a_, c_] :> TProduct[a, b - c],
   (**)
   TProduct[-a_, c_] + TProduct[-b_, c_] :> -TProduct[a + b, c], 
   TProduct[a_, -c_] + TProduct[b_, -c_] :> -TProduct[a + b, c], 
   TProduct[-a_, c_] - TProduct[-b_, c_] :> TProduct[b - a, c], 
   TProduct[a_, -c_] - TProduct[b_, -c_] :> TProduct[b - a, c],
   (**)
   TProduct[a_, -b_] + TProduct[a_, -c_] :> -TProduct[a, b + c], 
   TProduct[-a_, b_] + TProduct[-a_, c_] :> -TProduct[a, b + c], 
   TProduct[a_, -b_] - TProduct[a_, -c_] :> TProduct[a, c - b], 
   TProduct[-a_, b_] - TProduct[-a_, c_] :> TProduct[a, c - b]
   }

ClearAll[SimplifyTProduct]
SimplifyTProduct[expr_] := FactorTProduct[ExpandTProduct[expr]]

(*Define shorthand notation for (1 \[CircleTimes] a + a \
\[CircleTimes] 1)*)
ClearAll[Primitive]
Primitive[f_] := TProduct[1, f] + TProduct[f, 1]

(*Define the reduced coproduct, and it's associated rules*)
ClearAll[DeltaPrime]
DeltaPrime[f_ + g_] := DeltaPrime[f] + DeltaPrime[g]

DeltaPrime[f_  g_ ] := 
 DeltaPrime[f]  DeltaPrime[g] + DeltaPrime[f] Primitive[g] + 
  DeltaPrime[g]  Primitive[f] + TProduct[f, g] + TProduct[g, f]
DeltaPrime[c_?NumberQ  f_] := c  DeltaPrime[f]
DeltaPrime[f_/c_?NumberQ] := DeltaPrime[f]/c


ClearAll[aboveOneQ]
aboveOneQ[n_] := IntegerQ[n] && Positive[n - 1]

DeltaPrime[f_ ^ n_ ?aboveOneQ] := 
 DeltaPrime[f^(n - 1)]  DeltaPrime[f] + 
  DeltaPrime[f^(n - 1)] Primitive[f] + 
  DeltaPrime[f]  Primitive[f^(n - 1)] + TProduct[f^(n - 1), f] + 
  TProduct[f, f^(n - 1)]

DeltaPrime[PolyLog[1, x_]] := 0
DeltaPrime[Log[x_]] := 0
DeltaPrime[PolyLog[n_, x_]] := 
 Sum[TProduct[PolyLog[n - k, x], (Log[x]^k)/(k!)], {k, 1, n - 1}]

ExpandTProduct[DeltaPrime[Log[z]^3]]

ExpandTProduct[TProduct[x, y] + 2 (TProduct[x, y] + TProduct[y, x])]


Would using TensorExpand be helpful? Or are you looking for a way to have this happen automatically as a property of the function? TensorExpand[TProduct[x, y] + 2  (TProduct[x, y] + TProduct[y, x])  ]

Ack- I should have included in the original post. Yes, at the moment I am using TensorExpand as a temporary solution. It does the job, but I would like it to all happen automagically, at the moment I am having to call TensorExpand frequently. I also read here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/204385/distribute-dot-and-multiplication-on-a-sum in the comment by infinitezero that I should be somewhat careful using TensorExpand because it is sometimes slow (and I am indeed computing large messy expressions)

You don't need to do anything. Mathematica already knows that TProduct[x, y] + 2 (TProduct[x, y] + TProduct[y, x]) is equal to 3 TProduct[x, y] + 2 TProduct[y, x]. Try
Expand[TProduct[x, y] + 2 (TProduct[x, y] + TProduct[y, x])]
(* or *) 
Simplify[TProduct[x, y] + 2 (TProduct[x, y] + TProduct[y, x])]


You problem is that "symbol /: pattern" requires that the symbol needs to appear in pattern at most 2 levels deep. In your case "TProduct" appears at level 3.
What you can do is to unprotect "Times" and let MMA assign the rule to "Times". This is not very efficient because the rule will be checked at any appearance of "Times", but it will do the job:
Unprotect[Times];
c_?NumberQ  (TProduct[a_, b_] + rest_) := c   TProduct[a, b] + c   rest
Protect[Times];

Now if you write it works as requested:
TProduct[x, y] + 2  (TProduct[x, y] + TProduct[y, x])

3 TProduct[x, y] + 2 TProduct[y, x]

